# Magento check status of the review and then print

Tags: php, magento

I have following code to get all the reviews. It works but the problem is it's also printing the pending reviews. It should only print the ones that are approved.

```
        $review = Mage::getModel('review/review');
        $collection = $review->getProductCollection();
        $collection
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->getSelect()
                        ->limit($limitertest)
                        ->order('RAND()');
        $review->appendSummary($collection);
        echo '<ul class="testimony_slider">';
        foreach($collection as $product) {
           echo '<li>';
            echo '<div class="testi_left">';
                echo '<img src='.Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(100).'>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="testi_right">';
                echo '<p class="testti_summery">"'.$product->getTitle().'"</p>';
                echo '<p class="testti_nickname">'.$product->getNickname().'</p>';
            echo '</div>'; 
            echo '<div class="clear_both"></div>';                  
           echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to refactor your code to get the reviews collection, then filter by the **approved** status. Something like this:

```
$reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getResourceCollection();
$reviews->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED);
```

Comment: Perfect all i needed was this: ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED);